# DataGridView com colunas de diferentes tabelas de um DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

Importei 16 tabelas do meu *MSSQL* em um `DataSet` e fiz todos os relacionamentos necessários.

Estou precisando gerar um relatório em um `DataGridView` (ou outra ferramenta) com colunas específicas de diversas tabelas.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pode colocar o código que tem, mesmo que esteja incompleto ou com erro.

Comment: Bom, pra falar a verdade, ainda não tenho código algum.. rs
Queria o ponto de partida mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente consegui.

Para gerar os relatório eu usei o Crystal Report e para o problema de login eu adicionei a seguinte linha no meu App.Config:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Me desculpem a falta de informações e detalhes, mas estou numa baita correria!
Obrigado a quem respondeu!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar ReportViewer para gerar o relatório

http://paulohdsousa.blogspot.com.br/2012/01/relatorios-com-reportviewer-e-linq-c.html

http://www.devmedia.com.br/gerando-relatorios-atraves-do-reportviewer/5371

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Gerando-relatrios-com-815c3396

http://www.macoratti.net/pageview.aspx?catid=9

Comment: Vou tentar utilizar. Obrigado pelas referências!

Comment: Acabei utilizando o Crystal Reports pra gerar o relatório e consegui exatamente o que precisava à partir de um XSD que criei, mas na hora de executar o programa ele pede senha, mas o arquivo não está protegido. O que faço?